# Is there such a thing as a schema in a graph database?

Tags: database, graph, schema, graph-databases

Is there such a thing as a schema in a graph database?  For example, can you specify which types of node can have relationships with which other types of node?

What does such a schema look like?

Comment: Bear in mind that graph databases are far from being as standardized as relational databases adhering to a certain SQL version. So I think it depends on what graph database you use.

Answer (score 4):

Graph databases differ a lot in this area, just like [das_weezul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/300732/das-weezul) says. In the general case I think graph databases which are closer to object databases ([OODB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_database)) also have built-in schema support. One nice thing about graph databases is that they're very well suited for mixing data and metadata. So a common approach for both dealing with schema support and security is to store this kind of metadata in a (sometimes hidden) part of the very same graph.

When it comes to [Neo4j](http://neo4j.org/) - where I'm on the team - there's currently at least two approaches in use for defining schemas:

- Defining the schema in annotations, for example using [Spring Data Graph](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/neo4j) ([docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-graph/snapshot-site/reference/html/)).
- Using a [meta-model](http://components.neo4j.org/neo4j-meta-model/snapshot/) layer on top of the database.

You'll find some more reading on this topic over at [myNoSQL](http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/1035793263/infogrid-graph-database-schema).

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Schemas useful in selecting vertex labels, which are part both Neo4J 2 and Tinkerpop 3.  I think writing down the schema helps clarify how the graph should be used, although most databases don't support validations against a schema.

I have a longer post on how to draw the schema as a graph. http://lambdazen.blogspot.com/2014/01/do-property-graphs-have-schemas.html

Comment: I was very interested in your blogpost. Sadly the link is broken.

Answer (score 3):

A graph database will always have a rudimentary schema consisting of (at least) Vertex and Edge objects, where an Edge can contain data about a particular relationship. The degree to which you can add to this schema varies widely across implementations. You may be able to customize the schema by inheriting from Edge and/or Vertex objects,for instance.

If the graph database uses an underlying RDBMS or ODBMS then you may have access to more powerful schema creation and manipulation capabilities.